# Line-break in inline-links with icon in the end (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm using some anchor-tags inside a text.
They should have following requirements:

- Link can be multiline and should break correctly (no break between wrapping text)
- Icon in the end should not break alone (together with last word in anchor)

I wrote an easy codepen to show the problem: https://codepen.io/markus-burda/pen/wvPrpXw

When I change the display: inline on the .link to inline-block, the last word in the anchor-tag wraps correctly but the anchor wraps in newline:

[image]

When I leave it to display: inline the pseudo-element after the link wraps alone in the next line:

[image]

Do you have an idea to fix both issues at the same time?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}

.link {
  color: blue;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

.link::after {
  content: "";
  margin-right: -0.6em;
  height: 0.6em;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
  top: -0.3em;
  width: 0.6em;
  background-color: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnachtszeit kaufen sich viele Menschen vermeintlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Denn dann würde am Ende nicht viel Badevergnügen bleiben. Sie bräuchten eine Dusche nach dem Bad und die Wanne eine längere Säuberungsaktion, wie kraut&rüben berichtet.</a>.
  Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie), optisch ist der für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind
  die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnachtszeit kaufen sich viele Menschen vermeintlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Kurzer Link</a>. Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie), optisch ist der
  für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnahjjzeit kaufen sich viele Menschen Menschen Menschen Mens antlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Umbrder langer Link</a>. Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie),
  optisch ist der für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnahjjzeit kaufen sich viele Menschen Menschen Menschen Mens antlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Umbrechender langer Link</a>. Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie),
  optisch ist der für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: inline-block` for the `::after` pseudo-element when the element itself is `display: inline` is tad problematic. I'm not sure if you can expect for consistent layout results this way.

Playing a bit with your codepen, I tried to found a way to achieve something similar while keeping it `display: inline`. The obvious problem is that you cannot set a width to inline elements, and my solution was to use a non-breaking space (`"\00a0"`), a monospace font and `word-spacing`. Only tested on Chrome.

```
.link::after {
    content: "\00a0";
    word-spacing: 0.6em;
    font-family: monospace;
    background-color: currentColor;
}
```

Runnable version, based on the code in the original post:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}

.link {
  color: blue;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

.link::after {
    content: "\00a0";
    word-spacing: 0.6em;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin-right: -0.6em;
    margin-left: 0.25em;
    top: -0.3em;
    background-color: currentColor;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnachtszeit kaufen sich viele Menschen vermeintlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Denn dann würde am Ende nicht viel Badevergnügen bleiben. Sie bräuchten eine Dusche nach dem Bad und die Wanne eine längere Säuberungsaktion, wie kraut&rüben berichtet.</a>.
  Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie), optisch ist der für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind
  die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnachtszeit kaufen sich viele Menschen vermeintlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Kurzer Link</a>. Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie), optisch ist der
  für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnahjjzeit kaufen sich viele Menschen Menschen Menschen Mens antlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Umbrder langer Link</a>. Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie),
  optisch ist der für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
<p class="wrapper">In der Vorweihnahjjzeit kaufen sich viele Menschen Menschen Menschen Mens antlich eine <a href="#" class="link">Umbrechender langer Link</a>. Denn es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Ritterstern (Hippeastrum)&nbsp;und der Echten Amaryllis&nbsp;(Belladonnalilie),
  optisch ist der für Laien aber kaum auszumachen. Auch, weil die Echte Amaryllis nur selten im Handel zu finden ist. Das sind die Eigenschaften beider Pflanzen:</p>
```